# Mandelbrot set in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Where can i get the code to execute Mandlebrot set in tensorflow tutorials?
I already tried executing by pasting the code present in the website, but got an error near "import PIL.Image". Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are missing the PIL library, which can easily be installed using:

```
$ pip install Pillow
```

Also, you must run the code within a Jupyter notebook.

I don't know why they used PIL in the tutorial, I would have just used Matplotlib, which is better integrated with Jupyter. You can just copy/paste the following code in a Jupyter notebook, it should work fine:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Use NumPy to create a 2D array of complex numbers on [-2,2]x[-2,2]
Y, X = np.mgrid[-1.3:1.3:0.005, -2:1:0.005]
Z = X+1j*Y

graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    xs = tf.constant(Z.astype("complex64"))
    zs = tf.Variable(xs)
    ns = tf.Variable(tf.zeros_like(xs, "float32"))

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    # Compute the new values of z: z^2 + x
    zs_ = zs*zs + xs

    # Have we diverged with this new value?
    not_diverged = tf.abs(zs_) < 4

    # Operation to update the zs and the iteration count.
    #
    # Note: We keep computing zs after they diverge! This
    #       is very wasteful! There are better, if a little
    #       less simple, ways to do this.
    #
    step = tf.group(
      zs.assign(zs_),
      ns.assign_add(tf.cast(not_diverged, "float32"))
      )

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    init.run()
    for i in range(100):
        step.run()
    fractal = ns.eval()

plt.figure(figsize=(13,8))
plt.imshow(fractal)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```